# java.lang.NullPointerException in my code - Wrapper classes

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I've 4 classes. Let's say class: Graphics, Manager, DataInputOutput and Files.
In Graphics I've a method that calls another method in Manager that will call a method in DataInputOutput that will call a method in Files.

But I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception always on the method getCars() and I get it (the exception) for the classes DataInputOutPut, Manager and Graphics I know something is not initialized or pointing to null but I just don't get where it is. Can someone help me out here?

The call flow is like this: Graphics ---> Manager ---> DataOutputInput ---> Files

Here is the code related to the error:

Classe Graphics:

```
public class Graphics extends JFrame {

private Manager manager;

public Graphics() {
manager = new Manager();


(..)

tablePanel.setData((manager.getCars()));

}
```

Classe Manager;

```
public class Manager {

DataInputOutput io = new DataInputOutput();

    public List<Car> getCars()
    {
        return io.getCars();
    }
}
```

Classe DataInputOutput:

```
public class DataInputOutput{

private Database database;
private Files files;

public DataInputOutput()
{
    database = Database.getInstance();
    Files files = new Files();
}

     public List<Car> getCars()
     {
         return files.getCars();
     }
}
```

Class Files:

```
public class Files {

private List<Car> carList;

public Files(){
    carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
}


public void addCar(Car sta) {
        carList.add(sta);
}

public List<Car> getCars() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(carList);
}
```

Here is the stack print:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at controller.DataInputOutput.getCars(DataInputOutput.java:59)
at controller.Manager.getCars(Manager.java:41)
at view.Graphics.<init>(Graphics.java:125)
at view.App$1.run(App.java:27)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Comment: Where are you initializing `files` inside `DataInputOutput`?

Comment: You haven't initialized `files`.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I forgot to paste the code where I initialize Files. It's in DataInputOutput. I'll edit the code now in the question.

Comment: While you're at it, can you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

> ```
> public DataInputOutput()
> {
>     database = Database.getInstance();
>     Files files = new Files();
> }
> ```

the line

```
Files files = new Files();
```

does not set `this.files`.

It defines a local variable, leaving `this.files` with the value `null`.

Comment: Shadowing variables strikes again?

Comment: Oh man, that was the problem indeed! Thank you very much! Such a silly mistake, I guess I should go to sleep soon :)